# avoid duplicates in mysql relations table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `relations` (
   `idA` VARCHAR(20),
   `idB` VARCHAR(20).
   PRIMARY KEY (idA,idB)
)
TYPE=MyISAM;
```

and it basically just maps two ids together from another table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `scores` (
   `id` VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
   `score` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘0’,
   `friendsids` VARCHAR(1000)

)
TYPE=MyISAM;
```

So - if I want to add something to the relations table, I query

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO relations VALUES ('$idA', '$idB')
```

So the problem - it sometimes creates entries that have the same info but swapped between idA and idB. For example, if one entry is idA = 1, idB = 2 - I dont' want an entry that looks like idA = 2, idB = 1;

I tried:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO relations VALUES ('$idA', '$idB') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * WHERE idA IS '$idB' AND idB IS '$idA');
```

It gives me a syntax error which I somehow can't figure out:

```
Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE INTO relations VALUES ('saubua', 'deppata') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * WH' at line 1
```

Is there a chance I'm totally on the wrong way with this? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Can you show us the actual error you get please?

Comment: you have specify column name in where clause and use IN before second select

Comment: @TaryEast: Just edited the post with the error on the bottom

Comment: I would delete 1-2, 2-1 then insert

Comment: @krishna: idaA is the column name, and $idA is the string with the id that I want to add. What do you mean by second SELECT - there's only one?

Comment: How about reversing the logic? Whenever you insert x,y, ALSO insert y,x?

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
INSERT INTO relations
SELECT '$idA','$idB'
FROM   dual
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT idA
                   FROM   relations
                    WHERE (idA='$idA' OR idB='$idB')
                    OR (idA='$idB' OR idB='$idA')
                   )
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't add anything, except when idB is the same as idA (meaning a connection to itself). What is dual? Is that another database? I tried replacing it with relations.

Comment: Actually, I got it working! I changed it a little bit so it looks like this: INSERT IGNORE INTO relations SELECT '$idA','$idB' FROM scores WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT idA FROM relations WHERE (idA='$idB' AND idB='$idA') )       Thanks a lot Akhil!

Comment: Great work buddy, why don't you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

so - I took Akhils code and mofified it, so not it works:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO relations SELECT '$idA','$idB' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT idA FROM relations WHERE (idA='$idB' AND idB='$idA') )
```

thanks everyone!! :)